# How to link php file and jsp file

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have a HTML page in which I am using php for database connectivity and also I want to use onchange event of javascript for checkboxes.How I can link php file and jsp file? Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Do you mean you have a html code inside a php file and you want to include javascript file?

Comment: @ChiragSwadia in my html code my form action is going to php file

Comment: As far as I know, JSP is built with `java`. It has nothing to do with `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think you mean JS instead of JSP. If so, here's what you need to do

Add the below code in your PHP file. For example index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- app.js will contain your javascript with the checkbox logic you want to add -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
      <form action="./index.php">
         <!-- form elements here -->
      </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
   // Your form submission logic and database connectivity code will come here
?>
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted to achieve.